# Quarkus Graalvm native image creation failing

Tags: quarkus, graalvm

I am trying to create a native image of Quarkus application and it is failing with

> "Unknown Argument"

Here are the native-image command which is generated during build time:

```
C:\Program Files\graalvm-ce-java11-21.0.0.2\bin\native-image.cmd -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-DCoordinatorEnvironmentBean.transactionStatusManagerEnable=false -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=1 -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=US -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json -H:DeadlockWatchdogInterval=10 -H:+DeadlockWatchdogExitOnTimeout --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime --initialize-at-run-time=oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor\$XMLFactory,com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil,org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler,com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.SimpleType,org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.ColorMap,com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBase,org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler,com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper,org.wildfly.common.os.Process,org.slf4j.LoggerFactory,org.jboss.logmanager.NDC,org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger,org.wildfly.common.cpu.ProcessorInfo,org.jboss.logmanager.Logger org.jboss.logmanager.Level,com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory,org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.FormatStringParser,org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory,org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.OutputStreamHandler,io.quarkus.bootstrap.logging.InitialConfigurator,org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.Formatters,org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler,org.jboss.logmanager.LogContext,org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils\$KotlinDelegate,com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.logging.LogService,oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLUtil\$XMLFactory,org.apache.geode.internal.Version,org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils,org.apache.geode --initialize-at-build-time= -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy\$BySpaceAndTime -H:+JNI -H:+AllowFoldMethods -jar sample-app-runner.jar -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace sample-app-runner
Error: Unknown argument: sample-app-runner
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of Quarkus and what version of GraalVM are you using?

Comment: Thanks geoand for quick response on this. I am using "GraalVM Version 21.0.0.2 (Java Version 11.0.10+8-jvmci-21.0-b06)" on windows OS.  
Quarkus version: 1.13.7.

is there any known issue with the graalvm?

Comment: Have you tried with newer versions of GraalVM?

Comment: Still same issue with latest graalvm
[ERROR] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Unable to get GraalVM version from the native-image binary.
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildRunner] C:\soft\graalvm-ce-java11-21.2.0\bin\native-image.cmd .......-H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace sample-app-sb-quarkus-runner
Error: Unknown argument: sample-app-sb-quarkus-runner
Any pointers to resolve this issue?

Comment: What does execuring `io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildRunner] C:\soft\graalvm-ce-java11-21.2.0\bin\native-image.cmd --version` give?

Comment: Here is the output of requested commad:

C:\>C:\soft\graalvm-ce-java11-21.2.0\bin\native-image.cmd --version
GraalVM 21.2.0 Java 11 CE (Java Version 11.0.12+6-jvmci-21.2-b08)

Comment: Never mind. I am able to figure out the issue. There is the syntax error in the native command arguments. It is nothing to do with GraalVM version.

Thank you very much geoand for helping on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `quarkus.native.add-all-charsets=true` to your application.properties file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).